# I'm getting the association bonus only on one account instead of both. Why?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, association

I've associated my SO and Meta accounts - [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/955804/zoltan-toth?tab=accounts)

However got the association bonus only on Meta, but not on SO. Why is that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the association bonus, and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus-and-how-does-it-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check https://stackoverflow.com/reputation; on the bottom of the page you should see the following line:

> ** rep from bonuses: 100

It is right before the line showing the total reputation, and after the lines showing the reputation gained this week, this month, this quarter, and this year.

If then you look at [your reputation page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1499781/zoltan-toth?tab=reputation&sort=time&page=34), you will find a voice saying:

> +100 assoc Association Bonus

In your case, that is found for July 4, 2012.

> [image: screenshot]

You should gain it when you have at least two associated accounts, and in one of those accounts the reputation is at least 200.

Comment: Thanks, yes it's there

Comment: Sorry, its partial true, you need 200 rep and need to create account on another site.

Comment: @Lucifer The question is asking why the OP didn't get it on Stack Overflow, but did on the meta site. You indeed need a reputation of 200 in a site and at least two accounts, but since the OP got the association bonus, I take those requirements are verified.