# Take into account all of the reputations from all stackexchange sites

Tags: feature-request, reputation, voting, linked-accounts, association-bonus

I use the Stack Exchange sites very often to find solutions to problems and help me with decision-making.

In some sites I have asked question and received answers, and I have more than 15 reputation. On Stack Overflow I have always found answers to my questions and never needed to post a question (avoiding duplicate questions). **However, I would like to vote for the answers that helped me but I do not have the ability to do that, due to low reputation.**

Posting a question or answering an answer on each site seems like the only way to get enough reputation. 
Since I have no input to give in these areas unless they will be counted as duplications, many answers that I have already used are missing my vote.

I suggest to take into account all of the reputations from all Stack Exchange sites for voting, or thinking about a different way to allow votes.

Comment: Gain 200 rep on one site and you'll get a 100 point bonus on all the others.

Comment: see: [What is the association bonus?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141648/165773) "I was just awarded +100 reputation on all of my StackExchange accounts..."

Comment: Hi @Martijn Pieters Thanks for your suggestion. I am still far away from 200 reputation, and I think it is a waste that I will either not vote up answers that helped me out, or that I will answer questions that I am not 100% sure of etc. just for the sake of gaining reputation. Plus, it will be much easier to gain 15 reputation on one site... I believe that the fact that I have signed up to the sites and provided info on myself should suffice for my vote for answers that helped me. I still believe that the request should be considered for someone that has less than 200 reputation.

Comment: Same comment for @gnat. Thanks for taking the time to answer. I still believe it is too high of a reputation on one site and that gaining 15 on the actual site that is missing reputation will be easier - but I don't think it is correct to up your reputation to have the ability to vote up.

Comment: @ChrisF and the other members who decided to close as 'exact duplicate': I don't understand why this REQUEST is tagged as 'duplicate' - I did not ask 'why do I need 15 reputations', or about 'gaining 200 reputations on one site', 'how reputation works' etc. I know all that.  These so-called 'duplicates' do not hold the ANSWER to my request, and it seems like these 'requests' are just overlooked. Really disappointed that this is how things are dealt with on metadata. Will never again suggest anything on the meta site.

Answer (score 4):

This is already implemented, you just need a little more than what you've earned so far.

From [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work):

> - you associate accounts of two or more Stack Exchange network sites, and at least one of those accounts already has 200 or more reputation: +100 on each site (awarded a maximum of one time per site)

This association bonus is awarded to give you access to basic functionality like voting and commenting on the other Stack Exchange sites, as you have already proven that you know how to use those.

Answer (score 1):

Edit!

Approved edits (substantial ones are preferred) count for 2 points each.  This is a great way to get to know a site that is new to you and get a feel for the material it covers, as well.  Since they must be approved, you have a safety net while you learn to do this.