# Can a Stack Exchange association bonus be lost?

Tags: support, association-bonus

I recently hit 200 rep on Stack Overflow and got a big 100 rep bonus. Most know this as the 'association bonus'.

If I offer a bounty of 50 points and thereby lessen my 'base' score, do I lose that association bonus?

What if I offer a 150 point bounty and then work my way back to 200?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No. It's awarded once per site if you've ever had more than 200 reputation on any of your profiles, with the assumption that you understand the basics well enough to skip most of the initial restrictions. You can't lose this status, nor can you gain it twice.

Comment: Though you can certainly loose the priviliges.

Comment: True, and it even sticks if the profile you had 200+ rep in is being deleted. (and you don't have others with 200+)

Comment: @Deduplicator ...and the reputations.

Answer (score 12):

No. Once you have been awarded the association bonus it cannot be taken away.

Comment: [citation-needed] :-P