# Association Bonus reputation points, but no activity on any account

Tags: discussion, reputation, user-accounts, linked-accounts, association

> [You gain reputation when] you associate accounts of two or more Stack Exchange network sites, and at least one of those accounts already has 200 or more reputation: +100 on each site (awarded a maximum of one time per site)

Why [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3359886/gireesh?tab=summary) has `101` points on 3 accounts but no activity worth of 200 points on any site?

Did he delete one of his accounts where he had 200 points?

That would be the only explanation... but what is the answer?

Comment: most likely a deleted account, the association bonus remains tied to the SE profile even when the account responsible for the association bonus is deleted, so any new accounts, including recreating an account on the site where the original +200 account existed still triggers the bonus

Comment: Probably related to [this suspension](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1093209/gireesh) on another account of his.

Comment: @OGHaza most likely, I'd guess a sock puppet, upvoting his own posts and had +200 on both, the sock was deleted and he recreated the delete account so he could participate while suspended.

Comment: Just a note... though it hasn't happened in this case it's also possible to achieve this through bounties.

Comment: Another example is, [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/92461/svavil) user  who has 101 rep points, though his Activity tab is empty and they have only one account.

Answer (score 2):

A moderator will have to confirm, but the only explanation is a deleted account or a massive rep loss scenario.

As I was asking in [Association Bonus not removed upon account deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191415/association-bonus-not-removed-upon-account-deletion?rq=1), the association bonus appears to remain tied to the overall Stack Exchange profile regardless of what happens to the individual sites accounts.  When a user gets +200 on any site, then any associated account gets the association bonus.  If that original +200 account is deleted (or if the users rep falls below 200 due to downvotes or serial upvoting reversals), the association bonus remains.

Likewise, any new accounts that are created will also receive the association bonus, including creating a new account on the site with the original (and delete) +200 account.

Basically, it appears as if the system is set up to be once earned, the association bonus is never lost.