# Why does this user have association bonus

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, association-bonus

[This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/195683/user944513) user have 2 accounts: there and on Stack Overflow. Both of them haven't reached 200 reps yet. If not bonus, they both were at 1 rep. But he has association bonus.

**Edit**

[Look at it. (May 16)](https://web.archive.org/web/20140516044320/https://stackoverflow.com/users/944513/user944513)

Then [look at it. (May 30)](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:vhVhbkD7Zj8J:stackoverflow.com/users/944513/user944513+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk) (per Shadow Wizard)

Comment: That's a weird one. Deleted questions maybe?

Comment: The wonders of Google Cache: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:vhVhbkD7Zj8J:stackoverflow.com/users/944513/user944513+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk

Comment: He used same OpenID for the new account, thus kept the bonus. Think there's already a request to change this behavior.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, they received the account association bonus *here* on November 4, 2013. Considering that their Stack Overflow account is only even 3 days old, the only logical conclusion is that they once *had* an account with enough reputation which has since been deleted* (since you require at least two accounts for the association bonus to even kick in). Note that once you've gained the association bonus on any network account, [you keep it forever](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191415/association-bonus-not-removed-upon-account-deletion) and it continues applying to all future accounts even if none of your current accounts qualify anymore.

<sub>** Note that as a moderator on Stack Overflow I can confirm that this is very likely the case, but cannot reveal more detail than that.*</sub>