# How does the Site Association Bonus Work?

Tags: support, reputation, association-bonus, association

I was reading the FAQ on the site association bonus and it raised a number of questions on it.

I have looked at other answers for questions similar but I have still got a number of questions.

1. If I have an account with say 10 rep can I get 110 rep or does it only put my account to 100 rep?
2. Does it matter what account I get the 200 rep to the site association bonus?
3. If I lose my reputation on the site that has 200 rep does that lose my 100 rep added to the other sites for the site association bonus?

   Does this happen even if I have 200 rep on another site which I did not activate the site association bonus on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. It **adds** 100 rep to every site. If you have 10 rep on a site and you get the bonus, you will have 110 rep on that site.
2. You only have one *account*. If you mean "Does it matter which **site** my account gets the 200 rep on?", the answer is, no. Any Stack Exchange Q&A site (A51 does not count) will trigger the bonus.
3. No, you don't lose it. If you've ever accumulated 200 rep on one site, you get the bonus and can keep it everywhere even if you, say, award that in a bounty or lose it due to a deleted post/user. Corroboration [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164226/284336).

Comment: You keep the bonus even if you delete the account with 200+ rep, leaving you only with <200 rep accounts.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm hoping that all of this info will be covered in the [new answer I added](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus/303118#303118) to the related FAQ proposed question and that this and other similar questions can be closed as duplicates of that.