# Association bonus given after a long time

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, reputation, association

What is the association bonus? answers [One of the user's linked accounts has reached 200 reputation points, and as a result, all associated accounts are given a 100 point bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141649/186599).

But, see this [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1355704/girish?tab=reputation), who had earned more than [200 reputations](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1355704/girish?tab=reputation&sort=post&page=2) before December of last year, but he earned the association bonus yesterday only.

Why this happened?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The user only ever had a Stack Overflow account until yesterday - nothing to associate to.

Once the user created a Meta account and associated it with the Stack Overflow account - association bonus came into effect.

In other words - if you are only ever active on one site, you will never get an association bonus. If you have over 200 rep on that site and at that point create and associate an account on another Stack Exchange site, the association bonus will be immediate.

Comment: is it mandatory to create meta account or it's enough to open any other beta account

Comment: @Azik - Any other Stack Exchange site, meta or otherwise. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work

Comment: Worth to mention that only this very meta site is "independent" i.e. allowing you to create separate account for it; all other meta are per-site and you can't have "meta only" account.