# The Reputation Model for Voting

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting, privileges

I have been with StackOverflow since almost more than a year (as a user).
I have always been willing to contribute to StackOverflow by voting for the best contributions at the very least.

The problem is: I don't have the need to code extensively, so I really don't have any unique questions - all of them so far had been asked! And since I am much of a beginner to coding world, I really don't have answers to any questions as they are of a good stature!

I am able to find answers to my questions very easily on SO or Google.
But if I don't ask question, and if I am not good enough to answer a question - how ever will I be able to vote (to Vote you require 15 Rep!).
And yes, I have been helped by users extensively - I have over 50 bookmarks saved over my browsers for really good questions and answers!
All I have is 1 Rep on SO, I just can't vote!

What else can you do to improve your rep when you are starting off at 1?
Or at least, should voting be given a privilege to all the beginners?

Comment: I think you're seriously under-estimating yourself here. You should definitely be able to ask questions—not *everything* has been asked and answered on Stack Overflow yet! And you can post answers to questions that you *do* know—there are lots of "simple" questions that get posted, you just have to be in the right place at the right time. Monitoring the new questions for tags you're knowledgeable about is a good start.

Comment: @CodyGray - Stack Overflow has all those questions answered which _I_ have. 
And frankly, the simple questions - are really simple enough that should come up with a a little effort of using Google!
But yes, I will keep monitoring the new questions! Thanks. ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> how ever will I be able to vote (to Vote you require 15 Rep!)

You can suggest edits. Each accepted suggested edit will give you 2 rep. 7 of those brings you to 15.

When you see a post that can use some love - formatting, missing/malformed code blocks, typos, salutations and such, edit them - make sure you make them better (nothing too minor - a single letter change doesn't help anyone).

Comment: Again @Oded, I **can't** vote up your answer here! :P
But thanks.

Comment: @NiravZaveri And you can earn some rep here by accepting Oded's answer ;)

Comment: @Mołot Well, I will accept the best answer, definitely! But I want to see more responses if they come in. I believe this won't be the only thing (apart from Posting/Answering questions) I can do with 1 Rep, right?

Comment: @NiravZaveri - It is good that you wait. Too often I see newcomers accept the first plausible answer and not wait to see if other good ones come in.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that accepting also provides a bit of rep.

Comment: @Mołot - I did understand what you were trying to point out ;)
And I am sure to select the best answer, as anyways, I want to be a 'responsible' citizen to this place! ;)

But I had just another question then. If you have accepted an answer already, can you change the accepted answer to a new one?

Comment: @NiravZaveri It happens sometimes, but I don't know exact limits, restrictions and timings for it. Sometimes I regret you can't accept more than one (I happen to have almost the same problem many times and different ways for different projects can work for me).

Comment: @Mołot - Just to note. If you don't have any questions, you can't accept any answers. A bit of a catch 22 there for the OP.

Comment: @Oded well he has Meta questions. If he'll earn 200 rep here, he will get +100 on main site. But yea, I specifically did not post this as a part of my *answer* as I know it's not really an answer for his specific problem.

Comment: @Molot - True that. I think I will just earn good rep here! ;)
And Oded, that was a nice catch! :D

Answer (score 7):

You'll get an ["association bonus" of 100 rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus), when you get 200 rep on another site (e.g.  this meta site), using the same account. So basically if you earn 200 rep on any of the SE sites, you can vote everywhere.

Comment: That's something very useful to know about! :) +1

Comment: And you're well underway here already :)

Comment: :) Hopefully I can have more Meta Questions :P

Comment: Note that this is only true for this Meta - child-metas (for every _other_ site) inherit the reputation from the main site.

Answer (score 4):

Voting should not be available to just anyone. Many people would upvote posts they find entertaining and stuff instead of useful. And it would make sockpuppet upvoting own posts way to easy.

Watch for the newest questions in your favorite tag - biggest chance you will spot posts that needs edit, or sometimes ones you can answer because you just happen to know how to do it.

Comment: That's something I would definitely keep in mind ;)

Comment: "Many people would upvote posts they find entertaining and stuff instead of useful." - how would it differ for people having >15 rep?

Comment: @WebDevie - Now that I have asked a question, I understand the concept.
Initially, unless you are really a useful person, you will not be able to ask a good question or give a good answer, one that would be upvoted. And until you have asked a question/answer that is upvoted, you don't really gain the Rep - which prevents you from being able to do anything. 
The whole concept is - you have to do something useful before being able to even comment on someone or something's usefulness!

Comment: @WebDevie theory repeated many times on this meta is that making people wait and earn some rep before giving them privilege is to give them time to learn how this site is supposed to work. If someone manages 7 accepted edits, 2 upvotes on answers or 3 on questions, he shows he at least gets basics. And it prevents people who just stumbled here and don't participate from voting - think what could happen if question would get linked under nerdy webcomic ;) I like webcomics like that and I sometimes see what happens on forums linked under them.