# User has for each not active account 5 x 101 Points - is that possible?

Tags: support, reputation, new-users

I noticed a user with 6 account who seams to have only 1 account active.

> https://stackexchange.com/users/219674/pilgerstorfer-franz?tab=accounts

Is there a mistake or is it something I didn't understand correctly?

Comment: See [What is the association bonus?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Users with at least 200 rep on any one Stack Exchange site get 100 "free" reputation points when they join any other Stack Exchange site.

This is the "Association bonus". It exists so that experienced Stack Exchange users immediately get basic privileges such as commenting and upvoting on any site they join, without having to start from 1 reputation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I didn't know that...