# Shouldn't an Area 51 account that reaches 200 rep offer an association bonus?

Tags: feature-request, area-51, association-bonus

Perhaps this amount should instead be 250 (because the email confirmation gives 50 rep). I ran into a [user](https://stackexchange.com/users/3921220/sen2228?tab=accounts) who has >2k rep on A51 and he didn't give the association bonus to his other two accounts (which are at 1 rep).

Comment: Actually it's a bug. [According to a dev](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198424/no-association-bonus-for-area51#comment628956_198424), the bonus should be granted.

Comment: @ShadowWizard whether or not the code base says so (hence the bug), the question here is should it count.... so if you want to be ultra precise, I don't think it is a dup.

Comment: Hm....check out whether that user's other accounts are under suspension and/or downvoted to hell?

Comment: @ShadowWizard: The comment linked to is gone, so apparently it's not a bug. The "status-by-design" tag on the suggested duplicate would seem to suggest so.

Comment: @Fish yeah, Oded deleted it when posting his answer. Probably he took a better look in the code and found there's indeed no association bonus there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Shouldn't Area 51 account, when reaches 200 rep, give assoc if you have another accounts?

No.

Area 51 simply isn't your casual Stack Exchange site. It is completely different  and works differently on all points. On other network sites, we judge that if you reach that number of reputation, you should be able to use basic functionality on other similar sites since the overall functionality are the same.

In other words, Area51 doesn't give you any experience in using regular Stack Exchange network sites.

Answer (score 7):

### I don't think so.

Having 200 rep on Area 51 doesn't mean you can ask and/or answer questions well.

Comment: Ok, on MSE many my top posts are complete crap but farmed me bunch of rep. This doesn't mean I can answer questions well or ask good questions. However on MSE you get assoc if this is your first account to reach 200 rep and you have other accounts.

Comment: If your top posts are "complete crap" maybe you should fix them... But MSE still  follows the Q&A format. It may be more prone to rep-farming than other SE sites, but it's unlikely that you'll earn much without being at least *familiar* with one or more other SE sites.

Comment: Ah yeah, being *familiar* ;)  - does [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239626) require very much knowledge of how SE works? Just: 1. Find out this restriction 2. ????????? 3. Profit :D

Comment: @nicael True, but if you don't care about **any** other SE site, are you going to be looking for questions such as that?

Comment: No, but for "answering" this "question" I can get assoc, so as to have more abilities on the rest of sites (including a51, btw).

Comment: disagree with this reason... I can get 200 rep easily on any site simply by editing questions, and that certainly does not demonstrate I can ask or answer questions well.  The association bonus is effectively recognizing you are familiar with the Stack Exchange concept, so you are trusted with the most basic privileges on any site.  (although I still agree with the "no" portion of the answer).