# Why would a single up-vote get me 110 reputation points?

Tags: support, reputation, linked-accounts

To whom it may concern (Stackoverflow programmers, probably):
Possible bug.
I answered a question on SO this afternoon and my reputation points jumped by 110.  I went from 198 to 308 just by getting one up-vote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the [association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus), basically if any account has >200 rep then all accounts get a +100 rep bonus. The reason for this is to get you over the initial restrictions for new users on all sites but it does give this nice bonus on your "first" site as well. The low reputation privileges are all about using the site (commenting etc) rather than content level (eg voting to close) so if you've learnt to use them on one site you can be trusted to use them on all sites.

You can see this shown in your reputation history here; https://stackoverflow.com/users/1339950/philologon?tab=reputation And you will see the same entry in all your other accounts.