# After deleting all my SE profiles, SE still recognize me

Tags: support, user-accounts, deleted-accounts, association-bonus

I have deleted all my Stack Exchange profiles recently through support. They have deleted them all and all my user profiles in various SE sites have disappeared as expected. Now, I wanted to start over again and register from scratch, the problem here is Stack Exchange still recognizes me and still gives me the 100 free rep (sometimes). The first profile I created was [on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3177651/mih) and it was OK, then whenever I register it recognizes me as an old user and gives me a 100 free rep (while I do not have any actual rep on any site), for example here on [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/248595/mih) and on [Super User](https://superuser.com/users/291899/mih).

**Ooh yea**, what's even worse, my old user's chat messages are now mine! So the chat user is not deleted and my new user is basically the old user..

**Ooh yea again**, An [old question which was posted more than a year ago](https://superuser.com/questions/493535/is-something-wrong-when-the-force-close-screen-shows-as-empty-when-shutting-down) is associated with my NEW user profile in SU now! I thought when I delete my profile all my questions are de-associated from my profile. What's the story?

**Why do all the Stack Exchange sites still recognize me? is this an expected behavior?**

Comment: So you did **not** delete your original SO account?

Comment: You sure you're using different email and OpenID provider?

Comment: The fact that you are getting the association bonus and you don't have an account with 200 rep means that there is some tie to your original SE account (which would be the parent account of all of your individual accounts and ties all of your individual accounts together).  The Stack Exchange profile probably isn't deleted immediately when all of the accounts are delete, so if you used the same OpenID provider and same email, you new accounts just got reassociated with your original SE profile

Comment: @psubsee2003 so can you explain why my SO accound didn't get the bonus?

Comment: @MIH most likely timing.  It should get it by tomorrow when the scripts run.

Comment: @psubsee2003 check my last update to the question, an old question is associated with my profile again!

Comment: @MIH No idea (which is why I didn't leave an answer).  Somehow your old account is reassociating itself with your new account.  I'd guess it was because you probably used the same credentials and some automated script is reassembling your old account.

Comment: @MIH in case you missed my last comment, are you using different email and OpenID provider? If the same it explain this all.

Comment: @ShadowWizard to be honest I am not sure, I used my facebook account before, now I am using google. I also think I have linked google before.. not really sure.

Comment: @MIH so if you linked it before it means you're still recognized. To start from scratch, create yourself new email account, register new Stack Exchange OpenID account associated with that email, and you should be safe.

Comment: @ShadowWizard so I can assume that this is an expected behavior?

Comment: @MIH as far as I know yes it is by design.

Comment: This is .. strange, we're looking into it.

Comment: Well, maybe login scripts are written by Chuck Norris? Since they detect *old* you?

Comment: @TimPost thanks, I guess I was a pain in the neck and still even after deleting my account :/

Comment: @MIH No, not at all, this is just odd. I'll get back with better details once I have them - hang tight :)

Comment: @MIH: It's possible to remain logged into a chat account even after the corresponding account on the main site has been deleted. (I was in this state once.) Once you create a new account on the site, I think you'll be logged into the new account when you next visit chat, and forever logged outof the odl one.

Comment: All of these issues are addressed in the FAQ [How can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account) now: association bonus rights are retained even though one removes their profile on all sites unless it was through a data request (which didn't exist at the time), the question on SU was re-associated to the new account since it was migrated from Security to SU and the system provision to re-associate migrated posts if a then-unregistered user later registers kicked in, and chat profiles wouldn't be erased on user deletion at the time.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog 9 years later I totally forgot about this... thank you anyway

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Association bonus is still awarded if accounts are deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/266496/282094),  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/303118/282094

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bit of a fluke, and I've taken care of it. The SU question was migrated from another site over to SU. When you re-joined the site using the same credentials, it was reassociated with you. Remember, to the system - it looked just like someone had a question migrated to the site and subsequently signed up - I'm not certain we can prevent it from doing this in all cases where deletion was involved.

I've disassociated it *completely*, it won't come back. Regarding chat, [contact us](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) and we'll get it sorted out, but I'll probably need to involve a chat dev, so it'd be handy to have a ticket open for it.