# Association bonus is still awarded if accounts are deleted

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, association, association-bonus

If a user has an account with 200+ rep and at least one other with below 200 rep, if they delete the reputable account they'll still get an association bonus if they join a new site.

[This user](https://stackexchange.com/users/2107476/user177063?tab=accounts) is an example of this happening (they are using the bug - along with chat-parent deletion quirks to get access to chat without any posts).

Comment: Is it really necessary to target a user? I guess a moderator flag suffices. The bug stands on its own.

Comment: I really don't think that this is a bug.

Comment: Also, I don't really see the issue, although it could be 'fixed'. A user did earn the reputation after all.

Comment: @PatrickHofman What if the user is a persistent troll?

Comment: But does that have to do anything with the association bonus? Such accounts should be deleted SE wide in that case.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Fair enough, it's just that this case brought the situation to my attention.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm going to disagree with Patrick and animuson and state that I do consider this a bug in the association system.

On Stack Overflow, we've encountered many cases where sock puppets and their operators voted up their accounts above the association threshold and created accounts on other sites to establish the association bonus. We then deleted their Stack Overflow puppet accounts once we noticed them, but they were able to repeatedly recreate the Stack Overflow accounts we deleted, get the 100 point bonus again, and resume their voting puppetry from them.

In addition to the example posed in the question, [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306241/previously-deleted-rude-user-back-with-new-account) just happened today. Yes, it's an infrequent thing, but it has happened more than once on Stack Overflow and can be extremely annoying to deal with when it does.

Once an account that has received the association bonus has been deleted, it should not be able to receive that bonus again if it is recreated.

Comment: I agree with you for the specific case that a moderator deleted his account, as said in my answer. Those accounts should be nuked network-wide. In general, when it is just about deleting your account, it is not a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder myself: does a user earn the association bonus if he deleted the reputable account? In my opinion he does.

Deleted or not, the user showed he is capable of contributing positively to the SE network, at least a little. If you delete your account, for whatever reason, it doesn't all of a sudden make you a bad citizen (unless your account was moderator-deleted for example).

I guess this isn't a bug.

Comment: Was going to post a similar answer. Cheers! :)

Comment: Feel free to post another answer if you have more to contribute to this discussion.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Maybe there's a difference here between having that rep on the new site (slightly easier to get going without new user restrictions), and that allowing the user to chat with no/transient site accounts. The latter complicates matters immensely from a moderation perspective.