# Is there any benefit to keeping an account with less than 100 reputation?

Tags: support, user-accounts

If an account goes below 100 rep you can delete it and create a new one, recovering the 100 bonus from other SO sites.

Is there any benefit to keeping a sub 100 account instead of starting over?

Edit: To be clear, I'm asking for policy, not opinion.

Comment: Well if you keep doing it, a moderator is bound to notice and suspend you for continuing to contribute content that gets downvoted and then recreating the profile. *Everything* is logged and it's fairly easy to figure out who it originally belonged to.

Comment: So it is specifically prohibited?

Comment: Bypassing system-imposed restrictions from consistent low-quality content is prohibited. If you deleted your profile *once* because you didn't realize a site's rules and never did it again, absolutely nothing would come of it. If you deleted your profile ten times to keep removing negatively scored questions from your history, that's an abuse of the system and action would be taken accordingly. So it really depends on how far you went with it.

Comment: The system allows it. Citation that it's supposed to be a restriction? It's this a bug?

Comment: Just because you *can* do something doesn't mean that you *should*. As a moderator, if I find someone abusing the account association bonus by repeatedly recreating accounts, I will manually lock that account so that can never be done again. Frankly, I [consider it a bug in the system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/266496/135615) that you're able to recreate accounts and re-associate the bonus with them.

Comment: So you are using your moderator power to enforce your personal rules? I'm just trying to clarify that it's not an official policy, just you using your position to enforce your personal preferences.

Comment: See Patrick Hofmann's answer under your own link, for example.

Comment: @ゼーロ As you continue to use SE sites I think you will find that there are very few rules.  For example, search the [help] and I think the most you will find are mentions of a couple of "general rules".  What facilitates community input into how their sites work are that SE sites operate under a series of evolving guidelines that appear in an amalgam of [meta.se] Q&As, and a site's [Tour], [help] and per-site Meta.  I don't think trying to frame the [help] as a quasi legal agreement between a site's users and its moderators is helpful.

Comment: It's hard to know where you stand when the rules are "whatever the moderator feels like today". Meta isn't a substitute for a collection of rules, it's too hard to find decisions made on particular issues.

Comment: @ゼーロ Show me where that "rule" is written and any community consensus behind it and I will agree.  However, from what I have seen moderators are chosen for their consistency and fairness, and then schooled to be more so.  SE sites are guided by community consensus and moderators are empowered by a few extra privileges to guide and be guided by that community consensus.  I think it works very well.  I thought that during the 3-4 years before I became a moderator, and 3-4 years after becoming a moderator I still think it.

Comment: Can you convert that into an answer? Something along the lines of "there is no policy, only consensus", and perhaps include some details of how to determine what the consensus is.

Comment: @ゼーロ You've been told the rule that you would be violating.  It's prohibited to subvert the quality control mechanisms, which is what you would be don't.  That's not allowed, and so you would be punished accordingly.  This is not a moderator just "doing whatever they feel like", it's them doing their job and enforcing the rules.

Answer (score 20):

The benefit of keeping a low-rep account is not getting suspended or deleted on one or all SE sites for misbehavior.

When moderators delete an account we have to specify a reason.  One of the built-in reasons is:

> This user was created to circumvent system or moderator imposed restrictions and continues to contribute poorly

Just a few hours ago I deleted an account that was clearly created to bypass a question block.  This is not uncommon.

If you're creating an account, creating enough bad questions or answers to get into trouble, and deleting it to start over, that's definitely on the wrong side of the line.  Similarly, if you're accumulating flags or mod messages, or get suspended, deleting and recreating to get a clean record would not be ok.

So, you might say, if I create an account, get a single downvote, and cycle the account to start over, I'm clear, right?  I didn't trip an automatic ban; it was just one post.  To that I'd say: how many times have you done it?  If you've done it more than once or twice then, were that activity all on the same account, you would have tripped a ban.  So we're back to "circumventing system...restrictions".

Don't do that.  It will only get you in trouble.

No, I can't point to a page in the help center or a FAQ on MSE to back me up.  I write this from experience as a moderator on several sites for several years, and from seeing mod-private discussions of the kinds of shenanigans that people try to pull and what happens to them.  And animuson♦ , who is an SE employee and someone who might handle your appeal were you to file one, told you no.  That's clear enough for me, and it ought to be for you.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @ゼーロ: It does. You just don't like the answer. Unless you mean that "the benefit of keeping a sub-100 account is not getting suspended or deleted on one or all SE sites" should be stated more clearly, but I thought that was pretty straightforward.

Comment: Add that to your answer and it will have directly addressed the question. A citation would be nice, but at least you made it clear that it's just your opinion.

Comment: @ゼーロ why do you need a citation? You've been told by at least 2 moderators and an employee that this is the case

Comment: Because I've been told by at least one moderator and an employee the exact opposite. I'm asking what the official policy is, not what random people feel about it. I have edited the question to make that clear.

Comment: I doubt you've been told by a moderator and an employee to do what you're talking about and the people who've answered your question here aren't random people, they're the people who would be dealing with the situation if you did as you suggest.

Comment: By common sense alone, the policy on doing anything to get around system imposed restrictions is obviously, don't do it.

Comment: I'll email the staff member back and ask if I can post their email here. Obviously I won't violate their permission without consent.

Comment: Please delete this answer.

Comment: @ゼーロ Why do you want this answer to be deleted? It should stay.

Comment: So I can delete the question.

Comment: I think this question will serve as a very good dupe target for future questions that ask the same thing. It should not be deleted just to shed downvotes.

Comment: @fbueckert so it basically should be upvoted because it is useful. Done.