# Is it a good idea to delete and recreate my account if my first contributions are badly received?

Tags: support, user-accounts, low-quality-posts, deleted-accounts

If I ask a question, and it gets downvoted and closed, would it be a good idea to delete and recreate my account, to erase the question from my question record? Doing so effectively disassociates the question from the author, and can clean up my profile and not make me look as bad if all my post(s) were of negative score, or closed.

One may be tempted to do this. But is this really a good idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Users should not be able to wipe their record by requesting account deletion and then recreating the account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204783/users-should-not-be-able-to-wipe-their-record-by-requesting-account-deletion-and)

Comment: Duplicate of: [Is there any benefit to keeping an account with less than 100 reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300754/is-there-any-benefit-to-keeping-an-account-with-less-than-100-reputation) and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/327498/does-deleting-your-profile-and-starting-a-new-one-violate-any-rules

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## No

If you do this to the point that you're abusing the delete account feature to stay out of a question ban, moderators will become the wiser and you risk becoming [temporarily banned](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/). If you do this once or twice, you still probably shouldn't risk it.

I learned this from experience:

> Hello,
>
> We're writing in reference to your Meta Stack Exchange account:
>
> https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1370400/user1345541
>
> We've noted you deleted your account a couple of times; if you didn't, you'd clearly be [banned by the system from asking more questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997). Deleting and recreating your account is clearly not the right way to circumvent this.
>
> We really want you to have a good experience here, and the first step to that is making sure that questions you submit are clear, on topic and provide all of the information someone would need to answer. You may have noticed that questions you’ve asked weren’t well received by the community; they were downvoted and closed.
>
> There are a number of potential reasons for this and we’d like to help you diagnose exactly what’s happening. Questions may be downvoted and closed because they fit one of our [closure criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions), or are of the [type that we’d prefer users refrain from asking](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). While we’re excited that you’re contributing, we ask that you please take some time to read the information linked below - prior to asking another question - in order to assure the best possible experience (both for yourself, and also for other community members):
>
> - A brief [guide on how to ask questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)
> - A short summary of [questions we permit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
>
> Your account has been temporarily suspended for 7 days. While you’re suspended, your reputation will show as 1 but will be restored once the suspension ends.
>
> Regards,
> Meta Stack Exchange Moderation Team

Comment: I would say it's generally a bad idea to even 'mildly' try to get around system restrictions.

Comment: @JourneymanGeekOnStrike Hey Journeyman & others I edited my answer. Can you please re-evaluate it and consider un-down-voting? No pressure though.

Comment: @JourneymanGeekOnStrike on the other hand, a 7-day suspension is way milder than a question ban... the system seems to encourage this behavior.

Comment: Well the *first* time.  And we can't set a manual question ban. Bit of a loophole, but if someone exploits it, we're going to let people not to do it, and dissuade them from it with the tools at our disposal