# Deleting an account retains reputation and badges for linked chat accounts

Tags: bug, reputation, badges, deleted-accounts

I deleted my account on codegolf.stackexchange.com some time ago. The vast majority of my network reputation was derived from that site (I had approximately 20k rep when I deleted the account).

However, when I look at [my account on chat.stackexchange.com](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/246227), it's showing 22k reputation and six gold badges. These can only possibly have come from codegolf (I don't have nearly enough activity on other sites for that).

It seems like a major bug to retain this information; I can't see any good reason why a user should be credited for posts that they're no longer associated with. (It also concerns me that deleted accounts aren't being deleted "properly", e.g. I still have notifications from PPCG in my notifications list.) Note that part of the reason I deleted the account was to remove badges from it, and remove reputation from it without needing to use the disruptive method of continuously posting bounties, and as such I'm quite concerned that the reputation and bounties are still indirectly there.

Note also that it would probably be possible to use this mechanism to bypass the reputation cap; you could make a post, earn 200 reputation from it, delete your account on a particular site (as you still only have one post), create another account on the same site, earn another 200 reputation, and get a total of 400 "global" reputation. This would seem to violate the purpose of the reputation cap. (If this seems implausible – although in my experience, it's normally fairly easy to gain large amounts of reputation if you're merely aiming to gain reputation rather than to improve the site – consider instead the situation with bronze badges; you could create an account on a particular site, edit your profile to gain the badge, delete the account again, and repeat arbitrarily many times in order to gain arbitrarily many bronze badges.)

(See also [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266479/association-bonus-is-still-awarded-if-accounts-are-deleted), reporting a similar bug that affects the "can gain association bonuses" property of a global account, as opposed to the global badges and global reputation.)

Comment: Looks like it has updated now — it was probably just caching, as your chat rep is now 2.2k and no gold badges as expected. Chat rep doesn't update instantly, so that's probably why you were seeing issues previously.

Comment: Chat accounts normally get removed when the parent account they're associated with get removed (in this case your MSE account) - otherwise, they stick around and can sometimes take a while to get into sync with your overall network status. Rep shown for your chat account account doesn't quality you for any association bonuses though - so that's not an issue. Notifications once successfully delivered to your global inbox don't get removed because your account gets dropped...

Comment: @Aurora0001: That's fairly bizarre timing, as the codegolf account was deleted months ago; I wonder what prompted it to update? It was definitely showing the 22k when I posted this question. Also, it was definitely associated with the codegolf account; it appears to have changed to meta, presumably as a default.

Comment: When I looked I'm fairly sure it said **2.2k**

Comment: @ais523 if the account was associated with codegolf, that got removed, then I believe your chat account would have gone into a bit of a weirdo state if you then went back into chat and talked causing it to reassociate an old chat account that had a deleted parent user and then meh....

Comment: I know sometimes chat accounts also just don't get removed when the main user is and sometimes there's glitches where users suspended on main don't get suspended as they should in chat. Might just be one of those glitches... :)

Comment: @ais523 Have you actually used chat since that deletion? If you don't actively use the chat part of the account, it doesn't always update your profile there. When you started visiting it, the system decides to refresh.

Comment: @animuson: I had used it, but only for brief periods of time and not in a channel I'd previously spoken in. I only noticed the surprising 22k when I used it back in one of my "old" channels.