# Link all my Stack Exchange user names

Tags: support, reputation

I have joined a few different Stack Exchange communities and I have noticed that when I join a new one, like this, my reputation points go to `1`, even though I have more reputation on other Stack Exchange sub domains.

I am joining or logging into Stack Exchange via my Google account, and thought because I used the same Google account when logging in, my reputation points would transfer over.

I am not a reputation hog or overly concerned about *fake internet points*, but when browsing other Stack Exchanges and clicking other people's user names, I noticed (or thought I noticed) reputation from other sub domains seemed to transfer to the all sub domains. For instance, a guy in the DIY Stack Exchange has 2k reputation earned from the WordPress Stack Exchange *(just an example)*.

**So I guess** my question is two parts:

1. Is reputation on Stack Exchange websites cross domain?
2. If so, how does one link their Stack Exchange logins?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does "Reputation" work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) Specifically, see the section on the bonus for associating accounts, and [some of its existing dupes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a couple *types* of reputation on SE. There's per-site, and an aggregate network-wide rep.

Per-site rep is what we typically think of, because that's what gives privileges and that's what you get for asking great questions and giving great answers. Network-wide rep isn't--as far as I know--really *useful* for anything, but it does show up in chat and it's always fun to have. It's just the sum of your rep on every site.

At the 200 (I believe) rep level on most sites, however, Stack Exchange starts to see you as a "trusted member." As such, you automatically receive 100 rep points on all other sites. That's meant to just let you do the basics, like commenting on posts. Note, also, that this is only awarded once.

But no, long story short, rep is not network-wide.

You can tell whether your accounts are successfully linked when you scroll down on your profile page. It should show each site you're a member of there.

[image: Accounts]

You can also look at [my profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/263510/matthew-haugen), where you'll see that, although I'm relatively new to MSE, I do have a few thousand rep points on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1270504/matthew-haugen) and [Startups](https://startups.stackexchange.com/users/59/matthew-haugen). You can also look at my [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/1325646/matthew-haugen?tab=accounts) to see how the 100-rep-point bonus is issued (in light of my obsessive nature to join SE sites :) ). If you scroll down a bit there, you'll see a long list of sites with 101 rep, which is the result of the 1 initial point everyone gets, plus the 100 extra ones I received when first crossing the 200-point threshold on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer, very good information. I actually think that's a good way of doing. The rep reflecting on what the user contributes to the the individual stacks makes more sense; someone good at programming isn't necessarily qualified to be giving mechanics advice, and vice verse/so forth.

Answer (score 0):

1. No. It's per individual site. Reputation you earn on one site does not transfer over to another site.
2. It appears that your accounts are already linked together. Shows you have joined 6 sites here https://stackexchange.com/users/3761747/quoid?tab=accounts