# "You can only post once every 20 minutes"

Tags: discussion, rate-limiting, association-bonus

I have 15K reputation in one of the SE sites, I don't have such restrictions.

Now I entered a new SE site and I can't post twice in 20 minutes.

I think if a user is trusted somewhere he should be trusted everywhere maybe?

What do you think?

Comment: SE tries to separate its sites and it seems they do this sometimes too rigorously.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, I don't think that if a user is trusted somewhere they should be trusted everywhere. If this would be true the same would go for reputation and privileges. Notice that you're only throttled because you're below the 125 reputation limit to prevent (spam) abuse as explained [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/new-question-answer-rate-limits/).

In a new community it takes some time to get used to the specific rules for that site. You can't blindly assume that being good at Unix makes you a great member for parenting (or maybe I should have reversed those two but you get the point).

It will help though that you are an established user somewhere else on the SE-network and it won't take much to lift the restrictions given the fact that you are able to follow the rules and are familiar with SE philosophy.

And afterall getting 125 reputation shouldn't be that hard, on any site, specially if you take into account the 100 reputation [association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141648/165773) you get. It only requires 12 approved suggested edits to get at 125.

Comment: nice answer. /me agree..

Comment: Yes, you can't assume that being good in unix means somebody is good in parenting. But you _should_ assume, not being a spammer on unix, he won't be a spammer on parenting, too. SE seemingly tries to separate its different sites, which is quite understable, but not in this case.