# How can someone have 101 reputation on multiple SE sites?

Tags: support, reputation, rules

I came across this account and noticed that it has got a reputation of exactly 101 on more than 20 Stack Exchange platforms, even without posting any question or answer (see image below).
At first I thought it's due to the first days of SE when there hasn't been such strict reputation gaining rules as today. But then I saw that this is even true for accounts that have been created only half a year ago.

> [image: Screenshot]

So, am I missing something here like *"Take this online introduction tour and gain 101 reputation"*?
I'm asking because for me it takes quite a long time to gain enough reputation to become a productive member (voting, commenting, editing,..) on SE, especially when joining a new platform.

Comment: Can you link the account?

Comment: You get 100 points [association bonus](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus) on every site you join if **one** of your accounts has more than 200 points. I'm guessing that this user has over 200 points on at least one account, and then was given the association bonus.

Comment: @Catija That is true, one account has more than 200 rep. points.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is most probably due to the [**association bonus**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141648/162011). When you have 200+ reputation on any SE site, you get a bonus of 100 on each new site you register an account on (and that is linked to the 200+ site's account, of course), in addition to the 1 reputation point you normally get upon registering anyway. So this results in the very common pattern of 101 reputation you see.

Comment: So as soon as you hit the 200 on one account your other ones will get a bones of 100?

Comment: @JimMcAdams yes - as said so in the link Christian mentioned :)