# Share account reputation across different languages of the same community

Tags: feature-request, reputation, languages

I'm fluent in English and Japanese. I recently discovered that StackOverflow is also available in Japanese, and joined the community. However, the reputation appears to be completely separate from the English version of the same community. I realize the Japanese site is in 'beta' currently, but will the reputation ever be merged across languages? It seems like it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although sites might be similar each have their own topicness, rules, culture if you like and as such the trust you have earned in one community isn't one-on-one transferable between sites.

Once you get to 200 rep on any site you get the [association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus) on all other sites you have joined or will join. That is not limited to *similar* sites or sites with the same language for that matter.

Comment: I agree this is true for *different* communities. These communities are meant to be the same, but just for a different part of the world / different language. I'm not talking about some stackoverflow break-off -- I'm talking about the main stackoverflow English community and Japanese community. The communities have the *exact same* topic and rules, translated directly from English into Japanese. I would think the more overlap between users of these communities the better, since in reality they are really just a single community in different language groups (Japanese and English, in my case)

Comment: I beg to differ. IIRC so.pt do have different rules. Although they might share the topic, they do allow local variations.

Comment: Can you show me links of the 2 sets of different rules?

here are links for 2 sets of the *exact same* rules:
[English](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
[Japanese](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by "so.pt", so maybe I'm not understanding something.

Comment: SO.pt is Stackoverflow in Portugese. And the help center topics are similar  doesn't mean that on  meta everyone agrees on what is closeable, flagable, down voteable etc. That is not shared.

Comment: That's unfortunate that the Portuguese site is so different that the reputation would mean nothing coming from the main SO site. (aside from the association bonus, but that only happens once) The Japanese guidelines for the site are practically a word-for-word translation of the English guidelines. Perhaps they will change with time? Anyway, come to think of it, there probably aren't enough multilingual people who care enough for this ever to gain enough attention, so I guess I'll just leave it at that and accept your answer as correct. :P