# Feature Request: Some privileges are activated at 1 reputation

Tags: feature-request, reputation, privileges

As we all know, we earn privileges by earning reputation. But this is what I want to change; I want it to be so you can vote up, chat, comment and asking on Meta when you have any amount of reputation even 1. This is for all SE sites.

I am including voting up, chatting, and comment in this is because people would like to know how many people like their Q&A. They don't want be like *nobody likes this Q* Sometimes I 'm like that too. You don't have to make it so they earn reputation if the voter's reputation is below 15. Chatting is something everyone likes so people should be able to chat with less than the required amount. Sometimes people want to comment to understand the question more. I haven't been able to comment yet and I am struggling to answer question I should be able to answer. The last one I am really questioning myself on. People should be able to ask on Meta because a lot of people want to ask some question on how the site works. Of course they could come to Meta Stack Exchange but sometimes they might want to know something that is only on that one site.

The reason I want this feature-request is because on many of the sites I've joined you will see many places I only have 1 reputation.

Unlike [What is the association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus) this is asking about reputation privileges activated at level one; not asking how I got 100 extra reputation on all communities.

Comment: There's a proposal here, but it seems to not include any supporting reasoning or other motivation for it. Did you hit post too quick?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I did not, but as you think I didn't do it properly I'll edit it. Please check this again later.

Comment: Just keep in mind that there is a lot of existing discussion of why these particular privileges require reputation to unlock. You might want to directly address those reasons to demonstrate how they're less important than currently believed.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I am adding that to this Q

Comment: *"on many of the sites I've joined you will see many places I only have 1 reputation."* this is solved by the [association bonus](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141648/250962)

Comment: These topics have been discussed so many times on here, search around a bit. Also you will never get comments at 1 rep because spam. So, go answer a question or two then wait for a couple votes and voila, problem solved.

Comment: @JasonC - That's the problem for me. All my answers are always down-voted. I did look at the website you might ask me to go to.

Comment: Then work harder to write better answers (or questions), otherwise you don't get site privileges as a reward.

Comment: Whenever I see a post that asks to have the same privileges as someone who has ***actively*** contributed, and ***proven*** to be a valuable and responsible user, I know that user won't stick around for long. It seems that you want everything, and now, without even helping anyone. Helping other users includes "answering" and posting "suggested edits" = 2 points. Please take the time to read the Help Center.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the association bonus?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus)

Answer (score 22):

Erm. Why?

Having these restrictions act as a form of quality control. It reduces the value of 'robot' or 'sock' accounts for upvoting, spam in comments (spam questions are far more visible) and chat trolls actually need to make a minimal effort to get in.

A minimum reputation to upvote ensures people don't create additional accounts for crossvoting (or making votebots that randomly vote people). Some people just want to see the world burn.

Likewise for chat - one of our persistant chat trolls actually has to put in effort to post questions and answers, fails to do a good job at it, and lapses into frustrated site-trolling which is promptly smacked down.

Commenting? Maybe, but that's discussed elsewhere. People do need to understand comments are transient sometimes, but I guess it would cut down on people who read the rules, and decide to post an answer in lieu of a comment since they have not enough tep.

The required reputation for these things is minimal - 20 reputation is 2 answer upvotes for example, and would get you into chat.

You're probably going to "but that's too hard" - my low reputation sock (which I use for testing) got it with one answer. (I then went on to hit HNQ with my third answer, so its a *moderately low reputation sock*) While being a non programmer, I've also had an answer with more than 20 reputation attached to it on SO.

There ain't no such thing as a free lunch - the 'price of entry' to these abilities is quality content, and that's what seperates us from places like quora and yahoo answers.

Answer (score 13):

You *do* 'unlock' some privileges at 1 reputation: **[the ability to post questions and answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-posts).**

That said, any 'privilege' unlocked at 1 reputation isn't really a privilege, since *everyone* has 1 reputation as soon as they join any site: it's just something that SE allows all its users to do.

**Why can't every 1-rep user vote up, chat, and comment?**

- **Voting up good posts** implies some knowledge of what makes a 'good' post, which can only come from familiarity with the site - *at least*, the familiarity that comes from making one or two good posts yourself, which will net you that first 15 reputation.
- **Chatting and commenting** are secondary to the main function of the site, which is asking and answering questions. It's not necessary for every new user to be able to do these things as soon as they join. These abilities would also be easy to abuse: we wouldn't want a 1-rep spambot to be able to post thousands of spammy comments and chat messages without first having to pass some sort of test like being able to write a decent post.

Comment: For all of them could you make it so that once they stay for sometime and ask a few questions and at least one gets 3 vote ups they get to do these things. BTW - They should be able to ask in meta right away

Comment: @12944 That's how it is currently: if you ask a few questions and get 3 upvotes, then you have 15 rep and the ability to vote up; 4 upvotes, 20 rep and the ability to chat. And I believe new users *can* now ask in meta straight away - it's a relatively new feature.

Comment: @12944qwerty: New users, as of a month or two ago, can ask about *their specific post* on their site's meta, but not anything else.

Comment: @12944qwerty  It is also possible to earn rep just by providing decent "suggested edits", for every approved edit (by two established users) you get +2. You really need to to familiarise yourself with the "rules" and guidelines of the site, it's clear you haven't.

Comment: @12944qwerty don't forget you can always comment on your own questions and answers to your own questions before you hit 50 rep.