# I just earned the association bonus without reaching 200 reputation on any account

Tags: support, status-bydesign, reputation, association-bonus

5 and a half hours after reaching 185 reputation on Stack Overflow (the highest reputation I have on any Stack Exchange community), I received the 100 reputation association bonus for all my Stack Exchange accounts. As you can see in this picture, I only gained 184 rep, add that to the initial 1 rep every user starts with, and I had only 185 reputation. The [association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus) should only be awarded when a user reaches 200 rep not 185.

[image]

In this screenshot you can see that without the 100 rep association bonus non of my accounts reach 200 rep, and you can see in my rep history that I didn't lose any rep after earning the bonus. The reason my Stack Exchange account has 285 rep is because of the bonus, without the bonus it would have only 185 rep, not enough to get the association bonus.

[image]

Is this a bug, or working as intended?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A user accepted your answer and then shortly after unaccepted it. But the acceptance put you at 200 reputation for a brief moment so you were given the association bonus. Once given, the association bonus is never retracted.

Comment: Is there any way I can verify that this actually happened? even though it sounds plausible.

Comment: @DonatPants No. I can only verify it happened because I can see all the votes, including the deleted ones, on the post, and there happens to be a deleted accept vote that corresponds to when the association bonus was granted.