# How can we get moderator's help?

Tags: support, moderation, abuse

We just got a question on [Academia SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/91816/546) (now deleted).

Obviously, it's an abusive question. At the time it happened, there was no on-site moderator available. It took 11 minutes and ten downvotes and possibly 6 abusive flags to get rid of it.

How can we get urgent help from a moderator from other Stack Exchange sites or somebody who has the deleting power to delete this kind of question as soon as possible?

Comment: For those who could not see the post, I am not going to repost it here because it's too abusive. I am posting this question hoping that somebody can offer a better solution other than seeing it staying there for longer than ten minutes.

Comment: For context: The question described a person asking for help in committing a serious crime. So, the question here should probably read "how do we best report a person/post planning a serious crime?"

Comment: Considering how long such posts usually stays active on the rest of the Internet, 11 minutes are extremely good. I do not think there is any reasonable way to speed this up.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I used to see spams persisting there for hours.

Comment: Ey boss, pls can I have a picture of the post pls

Answer (score 12):

Flagging as rude/abusive is the first step, and definitely helps. Just one flag will send it to the moderator queue; six of them will nuke the post automatically. 
As @Tensibai notes, questions disappear from the front page and the /questions list once they have 3 or more red flags.

Chat is the best option in the Stack Exchange network for real-time collaboration. You can check the [main Academia chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2496/the-ivory-tower) and see if a moderator is active there (or at least more users to cast rude/abusive flags). Another option is to report the post in [Charcoal HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq); we usually do spam detection, but we occasionally help cleaning up abusive posts. As @rene mentions, you might find some helping hands in the [Tavern on the Meta](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) as well.

You don't need ♦ moderators from other Stack Exchange sites *per sé*; on Academia, they will just be regular users. But getting rid of these kind of posts is something the community can do on its own; it's one of the reasons we have an [association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141648/295232).

Comment: And after 3 flags the post doesn't sow up on home and question page IIRC.

Comment: Alternatively hopping into the Tavern might help as well. Some SE staff is ping-able there.

Comment: @Glorfindel Yes a -3 sore remove the question from the home page, but not from the question list pages, 3 flags makes it findable only by search. [Details here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/287976)

Comment: I am a long time user on Academia SE and currently have over 1200 helpful flags. I was 100% sure there was no on-site moderator available at the time it happened. That's why I asked the question. I had the experience that some spams persisted there for hours before it got 6 flags. I will consider the other options Charcoal HQ and Tavern on the Meta next time. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Alternatively, use "contact us" on the footer to have SE notified about the issue.

Comment: @Disney that's a good way to contact SE staff, but practically it's way too slow for this situation.