# Why does my DevOps@SE score not add up?

Tags: support, reputation

Can anybody explain why my score at [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/users/3920/amphibient?tab=reputation), at the time of this writing, is 113 when it should be 112?

[image]

Comment: hmm -- maybe the initial rep should be listed, like it's not

Comment: @amphibient the 1 point initial is the initial, this page list the additions, check the graph on your profile, you'll see it start at 1 and not 0.

Answer (score 3):

You *always* start with 1 reputation. If you add those, you obtain `112`. Then, you have to take the initial `1` rep into consideration and you get `112 + 1 = 113`.

Answer (score 2):

The required reputation to post a question or answer in any Stack Exchange site is [1 reputation](https://devops.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-posts), so when a new user is registered with any site, by default their account will credited with 1 reputation.

Since it is not earned by the user and it is provided by default, so it won't listed in the Reputation tab.

<sub>You can get [Association bonus as +100](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141648/312043)  if one of your linked accounts has reached 200 reputation points</sub>