# Editing The SE System

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where can I go to help make a positive change to the programming of the SE system? Stuff like reputation requirements and widgets that would be useful.
Is there an SE that users directly help in the programming upgrades that are rated just like this question?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Stack Overflow is a [company](https://stackoverflow.com/company) and employs developers who maintain and change the software behind the Stack Exchange network. Normal users, and even ♦ moderators, cannot change it.

If you want to have something about that software changed, you can post a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) on Meta Stack Exchange. Be sure to specify what problems your feature request addresses; just *Lowering raising the bar in fields like in down voting privileges* is not enough. One of the reasons it's set at more than 100 reputation is that if it weren't, lots of users would be able to downvote on any site because of the [association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141648/295232).

Also, most successful feature requests are posed by users who have much experience here, even more than me. You'd be amazed at the amount of thought which has been put over the years into the system as it currently works. It'd be truly remarkable if somebody who has been a member for just a month would be able introduce more than just a minor structural improvement to the sites.

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning that [SEDE][(http://data.stackexchange.com/) is open-source as some of the components used, see their GitHub: https://github.com/StackExchange

Comment: "*...if it weren't, lots of users would be able to downvote on any site because of the association bonus.*" You say that as though it would be a bad thing. IMO it would help to reduce the brokenness of the HNQ.

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand, there is already a way to change the amount of reputation needed for certain privileges. For example, on this very site, the ["Comment Everywhere" privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) is unlocked at 5 rep (where it is 50 on other sites) and [downvoting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down) is unlocked at 100 (where it is 125 on other sites).

If you want to see the reputation thresholds changed you will need to convince the community first on the appropriate child meta and then a CM can take care of making the change. This is what [PPCG](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7084/66025) did.

I'm not sure what you mean by "widgets", but things like Mathjax and video embeds are enabled on a case-by-case basis in much the same way—convince everyone that it is needed for the site on meta.

I also know that people have made userscripts in the past that were very useful that have been added as a permanent addition to a specific site (such as the [Hebrew virtual keyboard](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1806) on Mi Yodeya and the [chess replayer](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3) on the Chess site). Again, you would need to convince people that it's something worth having on the site, and that it's worth the drawbacks, whatever they may be.