# Why do we use [bonus-reputation] instead of [association-bonus]? Let's not!

Tags: support, status-completed, meta, retag-request, association-bonus

**Everyone** calls it the "association bonus". Is there a historical reason for this?

Can we please *at least* synonymize the two or (preferably for me) make [association-bonus](/questions/tagged/association-bonus) the master tag?

On our [FAQ for the association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus), we refer to it as such. We never refer to it as "bonus reputation". If this is the *de facto* term, let's use it in our tag - please!

Comment: Did my question remind you of this? :D

Comment: ... Sorta. When I retagged it, I realized the stupidity of this existent tag and felt the urge to rectify it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#SeemsLegit

Merged and synonymized [bonus-reputation](/questions/tagged/bonus-reputation) `->` [association-bonus](/questions/tagged/association-bonus).