# Does reputation on sites with site-specific chat servers count toward the ability to chat on the general Stack Exchange chat server?

Tags: support, reputation, chat, privileges

In other words, say, if I have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow, does it count toward the ability to chat on https://chat.stackexchange.com/?

Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange have their own chat servers, that are apart from the "general" chat server that handles all other sites.

The [privilege FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared) wasn't clear about this. Also, from what I can tell, my Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange reputation *are* counting toward my [general chat reputation](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/78973/gparyani) (it equals the sum of all my accounts where I have at least 200 reputation, including SO and MSE, taking into account caching). I also remember the moment when that sum total crossed 10,000, and at that moment I was granted the ability to see chat flags. But since the algorithm for calculating Chat.SE reputation changes once a user has the network association bonus rights, it might work differently when a user does not.

When considering whether someone has the requisite 20 rep to chat, does the system on Chat.SE consider reputation on Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange? Ideally I'd prefer it if someone tested this out.

Comment: You could figure this out by going to your profile page on each chat server and see what reputation it says you have and compare those numbers to your rep on the respective sites. You appear to already understand that you could do this, and have sort-of done so. I'm not really sure what you are asking.

Comment: @Makyen I received [this comment from a CM](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus/303118#comment1074954_303118) which states that it's not possible to chat on Chat.SE with just 20 rep on Stack Overflow and no rep elsewhere. But according to my research, it should be possible. I'd prefer if someone tested this out. (By the way, Shog [said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1018864) that I should still verify statements I'm skeptical of, even if they happen to come from employees.)

Comment: The CM may, or may not, be technically correct. An account on a non-SO SE site may be required. I failed to test just trying to log-in to chat.SE with my test account prior to creating an account on Meta.SE. My test account with 21 rep on SO and 1 rep on Meta.SE shows 22 rep on chat.SE and is able to post chat messages on chat.SE, but not chat.Meta.SE (where it has 1 rep).

Comment: @Makyen (prior comment deleted) Mind testing on a new account that *only* has an SO account and 20 rep on it?

Comment: Getting *exactly* 20 rep is non-trivial. :-) I think I have another test account, but I don't recall what state I left it in.

Comment: @Makyen 20+ rep is fine, as long as it *only* has an account on SO and doesn't have the association bonus.

Comment: @starball Not a duplicate. As per my first comment here, this question was asked in response to a staff comment which directly contradicted the answer there, which itself is based on staff comments. The purpose of this question was to ask if said staff comment was indeed correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes, it does**.

As an example, you can see [Natty](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/256700/natty) in the [SEBotics room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54445/sebotics). While the bot usually has [explicit write access](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/54445/sebotics?tab=access&highlight=256700), I temporarily removed that special access to test. The bot has 53 rep on Stack Overflow. Even after I revoked the access, the bot was still able to [chat in the room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54445/sebotics), responding to commands.

[image: screenshot of test, with where the explicit access was revoked marked]

In addition, Natty regularly chats in [The Raiders of the Lost Downboat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/3877/raiders-of-the-lost-downboat?tab=access), an Ask Ubuntu room, without any explicit access. I'm afraid that Catija was mistaken here. :/