# Notification on achievements dialog doesn't take account deletion into account

Tags: bug, top-bar, deleted-accounts, achievements-dialog

A minor issue with the notification on the achievements dialog in the top bar: it doesn't seem to properly handle account deletions.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Have an account with enough reputation to qualify for the [association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141648/295232)
2. Join a new community
3. Delete your account on that community
4. Join the community again
5. The notification on the trophy icon in the top bar will show +200, even though there's only +100 'unread' reputation in the dialog itself.

I suspect that if I'd earned some additional reputation on the site (by upvotes or approved suggested edits) between steps 2. and 3. it wouldn't be subtracted from the notification either.

[image]