# Do Stack Exchange Staff start with 101 reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I have seen and experienced reputation 1 at the beginning. But I have encountered a few people where they have already got 101 rep in their wallets without answering or asking even once.

As far as I know, sharing reputation among SE sites wasn't allowed. So, is it that the employees of SE are given 101 rep at the beginning for proper maintenance and such?

Comment: [Association Bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus)

Comment: I don't know with what reputation staff start but every user gets an "association bonus" of 100 reputation on any new site they join once they have 200 rep on one of their accounts. See the answer to this question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus –– As this question asks about staff, it is not a duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: I got it ........Should I delete the question ?

Comment: Sristy, you *could* delete the question if you wish, but the way I read it is that you are asking: "Do employees get 101 reputation on their **first**, and subsequent sites?"; which I'm not sure is a duplicate. Related is "Why they sometimes have 101, yet othertimes they manage to get downvoted to 99 (less than 101)?" - so the ***question*** (singular) being: "How does employee reputation work?" (because sometimes employees have more than 101 reputation). **But** it's ***your*** question, ask/do as you wish.

Answer (score 10):

Not necessarily. They have a *staff flag* - which may give them special powers. In addition they may get the same diamonds we mods got as needed, although it is primarily given only to community managers.

Otherwise employees have the same reputation system we do - many SE staff already start in the community (so have pre-existing reputation), and they can lose reputation.

More or less, folks get the abilities they need to moderate *without* the reputation with the appropriate flag set on their account.

Answer (score 6):

The [other answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337425/295232) is correct, but it's always nice to have an example. [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/287938/will-westendorf) is a staff member with only 1 reputation on most sites, including Meta Stack Exchange:

[image]

> So, is it that the employees of SE are given 101 rep at the beginning for proper maintenance and such?

Even if that were the case, 101 reputation doesn't give much [maintenance privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges?tab=moderation); all you can do is voting, flagging and commenting.

Comment: Wonder if 1 rep staff member can: 1) Vote, 2) Comment anywhere, 3) Flag, etc..

Comment: I don't think so (but I could be wrong). The only additional power I've *seen* so far is the ability to suggest edits adding [tag:status-completed] and ilk.

Comment: @Shadow and Glorfindel: that might depend on whether they're staff with a *diamond* or just vanilla staff, maybe? The diamond might confer some powers that just a staff flag doesn't.