# Is this question part of a cryptocurrency scam?

Tags: discussion, spam

I came across this question by chance [How do I recover from a cryptocurrency scam?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/91943/how-do-i-recover-from-a-cryptocurrency-scam). It is the first question of this account and it directly accepted an answer by another fresh account. The accepted answer has only 2 upvotes at the moment unlike the second one which has 31.
The accepted answer is also the only one which mentions a way to get the money of the OP back. All other answers say the money is lost.

The mentioned company to recover the money has a nice website with no real content, no google reputation besides their own Facebook page, their domain is indexed since just 3 months, their Facebook page is from august this year and has also no noteworthy content beside stock photos.

So it looks like a scam to me. Also is there a feature to directly report questions as spam/scam?

Comment: By clicking that little "flag" link below the question. But requires you to be a member of that community, and have the required reputation (which is like "5" for "flagging?!)

Comment: That company's website contains an interesting philosophy: _"Our Philosophy
Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia con- sequuntur magni dolores"_ That's a lorem ipsum... On _"the number 1 go to service center to recover lost funds"_. To quote a famous admiral: ___"It's a trap!"___

Comment: Derp, corrected that.

Comment: I was initially suspicious, but clearly only a really high-class company would have their philosophical statement in Latin.

Comment: @Kyralessa: caveat emptor.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Also is there a feature to directly report questions as spam/scam?

Yes, you can cast a custom moderator flag to draw their attention to this (admittedly rather peculiar) situation. They might be able to infer some connection between these users. You'll need [15 reputation](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to do so, though, so I've cast the flag for you now. I have also cast a flag [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/91989/42185) on a similar looking post.

Another reason for you to gain a little bit more reputation on Stack Overflow (or another site in the network; with a little luck this very question may already earn you enough reputation) so that you qualify for the [association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus). This will enable you to act on strange situations across the *entire* network.

Comment: "gain a little bit more" ... can be quite hard. Unless you put up a really nice thing here on MSE, or maybe SO ... it takes time to get to 200.

Comment: @GhostCatsaysReinstateMonica Ask a question about recent proliferation and you'll get 20 upvotes in a few hours :)

Comment: Kaboom! OP got the bonus now. ;)

Comment: @ShadowThePrincessWizard Sure, that is why excluded MSE ;-) ... when you "work" on one small community, the road to 200 rep might be rather lengthy.