# How can I merge/combine all Stack Exchange accounts?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support, user-accounts, merge-accounts

Is it possible to **merge** all [Stack Exchange Sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#) accounts like [StackOverflow](https://www.stackoverflow.com) & [AskUbuntu](https://www.askubuntu.com), [SuperUser](https://www.superuser.com),  *etc*. so that the **trust** *(impact, reputation and badges)* of all accounts gets added up into one single place.

With this, users with **high trust** on one of the Stack Exchange Site could directly answer or comment on some questions without first collecting the reputation again..!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the association bonus?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus)

Comment: Yes it does. Thank You =)

Comment: Downvoting this was excessive, especially for a new user's question.  +1'd by me back to zero.  C'mon pedants.

Comment: I like the idea. We could add the main site names as kind of super tags and have only a single account. The points in the tags may then become more important.

Comment: Yeah exactly, also by doing this the badges a user collects will be one time, so the user can focus on a different badge progress!