# What is reputation's association bonuses' link leads to a 404

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center, blog, association-bonus

1. Go on any [What is reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) page. (Tested on Meta Meta, [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) and [Travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation))
2. In the "How do I earn reputation?" section below the list there is a link for association bonuses.
3. Click on "[association bonuses](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/cross-site-account-associations/)".
4. Get a 404.

Please can the post or link be restored?

Comment: For those of you interested in the post: http://web.archive.org/web/20190407223102/https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/08/cross-site-account-associations/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Switched this to link to the [MSE FAQ for the Association Bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus-and-how-does-it-work). Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Whew, you're quick!

Comment: It was reported on MSO already and I'd been planning to fix it but I forgot 