# Can there be a 10% bonus between site reputation?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, association

The reputation between sites isn't linked, because each site is slightly different. And I get that. However, I read that reputation is how much the community **trusts you.** If the community trusts me on Stack Overflow, it should assume that I am trustable, not just a trusted coder.

Because the sites are not exactly the same, I think you should earn 10% of what you earn on a different site and lose 25%. The reason that the loss is 25% is that if I troll on one site, I am a troll period and that should be taken into account.

Comment: Do you know about the [Association Bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141648/323179)? Doesn't that already solve this issue?

Comment: @lionrock _"I am a troll period and that should be taken into account."_ Huh, what please??

Comment: You're not _trustable_ at StackOverflow, because your network wide score is to low and you apparently didn't post any useful content there.

Comment: This is wrong for many reasons, but the major reason is that reputation has nothing to do with trust, in the basic level. It's given per-post. There is a bonus of 100 reputation, given on **all sites** once you reach 200 in a single site, and that's enough to get the basic privileges. And as for trolls, if one really troll more than one site, there's a network wide suspension available to be cast.

Comment: Sounds too complicated.

Comment: @KevinB technically? Not really, there are already cross site jobs running, so when getting upvote it's possible, in theory, to add 1 rep on all other sites. Downvotes would be more tricky, e.g. taking 1 reputation down on all sites for every two downvotes you get on one site. Still, that's surely not the reason to object to this request, IMO.

Comment: I think modifying the association bonus is not necessary.

Comment: What would be complicated is clearly indicating to users where their rep is coming from/going. Not only to the users themselves, but others who view their profile. Would rep from hidden communities also cross?

Comment: @KevinB well yes, when seeing user with no activity and no other accounts but with 101 reputation, it's usually due to reputation bonus on a hidden site. So that won't be very different.

Comment: 100, one time, is much easier to explain than a weekly or daily +n phantom rep